# Make SymPy to simplify functions with custom properties

Tags: python, sympy

#### Context

Let's say I have a blackbox mathematical  function `p(n,k)`, for which I know the following property holds:

```
p(n, 2) * p(n, 2**l) =  p(n, 2**l)
```

As a consequence `(p(n,2) - p(n,4)) * (1 - p(n,2))` vanishes.

I am tryig to set up a system (possibly with python) where I can put this kind of expressions and get a simplified version. For this reason `SymPy` looks the best solution out there.

#### The problem

`SymPy` is excellent in simplifying standard mathematical functions and polynomials, however, how can I add simplification rules to `sympy` in order to make it possible to simplify custom functions?

Comment: From `p(n, 2) * p(n, 2**l) =  p(n, 2**l)` it follows that `(1-p(n,2))*p(n,2**L) = 0` . This can only happen if `p(n,2)=1` or if `p(n,2**L)=0`.

This type of problem, when a property of a function is known (without being given the function definition itself), and the question is to find the functions that have this property, I think that's called [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation). 

Would be useful if you carry out the entire argument manually in your post (What functions `p` are the solutions?). After that, we can think of a way to automate via SymPy.

Comment: @wsdookadr, indeed, `p(n,2 **l)` is deifned only on integers. My question, on how to deal with integer-only functions would have been my second step. In particular `p(a,b) = 1 if a%b==0 else 0`

Comment: In the first case (`p(n,2)=1`) there's a lot of functions that satisfy this property. Here's some: `p(x,y)=y**2-3` or.. [`p(x,y)=binomial(x,(x-y+2))`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+binomial%28x%2C%28x-y%2B2%29%29+at+x%3Dn%2Cy%3D2) . For the second case (`p(n,2**L)=0`) you can have for example `p(x,y)=0` or `p(x,y)=y mod 2` or [`p(x,y)=JacobiSymbol(x*y,y)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=evaluate+JacobiSymbol%5Bx*y%2Cy%5D+at+x%3Dn%2Cy%3D2+) . Maybe you need more information about the function you're looking for.

Comment: You add your own simplification rules to sympy by making a function that does the simplification that you want. The answer to your followup is to use `Piecewise` or `KronckerDelta`.